# Magento: How do I put widgets into a layout xml?

Tags: php, xml, widget, magento

I am using Magento Enterprise Edition. It includes a widget for banners, which I want to use inside of my template, rather than from inside of a CMS-run content block. I succeeded in generating the output from inside of a content block:

```
{{widget type="enterprise_banner/widget_banner" display_mode="fixed" rotate="series" banner_ids="4" template="banner/widget/block.phtml" unique_id="744a56c9a042cc9fa166163c12d869d9"}}
```

Simple enough. So inside of my layout xml, I tried this:

```
<block type="enterprise_banner/widget_banner" name="hero_banners" as="hero_banners" display_mode="fixed" rotate="series" banner_ids="4" template="banner/widget/block.phtml" unique_id="744a56c9a042cc9fa166163c12d869d9" />
```

Same parameters; I just added name and as. And then, inside of my template...

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('hero_banners'); ?>
```

But I get no output. The profiler notes that the hero_banners block is loaded, but its template file (banner/widget/block.phtml) is never run.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

-P

Answer (score 19):

Turns out, it wasn't inserting any meaningful data because it wasn't receiving its parameters. It needs non-standard parameters to be set through action tags:

```
<block type="enterprise_banner/widget_banner" name="hero_banners" as="hero_banners" template="banner/widget/hero.phtml">
    <action method="setDisplayMode"><value>fixed</value></action>
    <action method="setBannerIds"><value>4</value></action>
</block>
```

Comment: This only seems works (at least in 1.6.2) if the widget block is a child of a core/text_list block, putting a widget like this straight into the root block doesn't appear to render.

Answer (score 2):

Since the topic has already been solved, I have an off topic solution

This could be set as a block within a .phtml file if required.

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('enterprise_banner/widget_banner')->setBannerIds('4')->setDisplayMode('fixed')->setTemplate('banner/widget/block.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```